# Query selector /3a

Tags: seletores, jquery-select2, css-seletores

Estou fazendo `js` de `htmls` complexos que não foram estruturados por mim.
Para facilitar uso o Firebux ou o `Chrome Developer` para copiar o seletor pronto. Eles me retorna esse seletor:

```
#dadosCadastrais\3a dadosCadastraisPessoaTable\3a 0\3a j1_data > tr > td:nth-child(1)
```

Mas o navegador não entende esse `\3a`

Eu quero capturar a tag: `<td role="gridcell">Paulo Henrique</td>`

A estrutura html é essa:

```
<form target="_self" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="http://pcnisapr02.prevnet/cnis/faces/pages/requerimento/painelcidadao/painelCidadao.xhtml" method="post" name="dadosCadastrais" id="dadosCadastrais">

    <span id="dadosCadastrais:dadosCadastraisContainer"><div class="ui-datatable ui-widget center-block dtp-painel-datatable" id="dadosCadastrais:dadosCadastraisPessoaTable">
            <div class="ui-datatable-header ui-widget-header ui-corner-top">
                <div class="btn-toolbar">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <span class="ico-user"></span> Dados Cadastrais
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-datatable-tablewrapper"><table role="grid">
                    <tbody class="ui-datatable-data ui-widget-content" id="dadosCadastrais:dadosCadastraisPessoaTable_data">
                        <tr role="row" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-even" data-ri="0">
                            <td role="gridcell">
                                <div class="ui-datatable ui-widget" id="dadosCadastrais:dadosCadastraisPessoaTable:0:j1">
                                    <div class="ui-datatable-tablewrapper">
                                        <table role="grid">
                                            <tbody class="ui-datatable-data ui-widget-content" id="dadosCadastrais:dadosCadastraisPessoaTable:0:j1_data">
                                                <tr role="row" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-even" data-ri="0">
                                                    <td role="gridcell">Paulo Henrique</td>
                                                    <td role="gridcell">Casa</td>
                                                    <td role="gridcell"></td>
                                                    <td role="gridcell">09/09/1993</td>
                                                    <td role="gridcell">27/12/2011</td>
                                                    <td role="gridcell">Nit normal</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></span>
</form>
```

Comment: pode atualizar a resposta com a estrutura HTML que você quer capturar?

Comment: Atualizado. Como disse o código veio pronto, infelizmente não posso mudar a estrutura do html.

Comment: Pelo código, o \3a é referente ao : do id dadosCadastrais:dadosCadastraisPessoaTable:0:j1_data

Comment: Se este HTML for fixo, a primeira TD desta tabela pode ser capturada com o código document.getElementById('dadosCadastrais:dadosCadastraisPessoaTable:0:j1_data').querySelector('td')
Se for o que você espera, escrevo como resposta explicando o código